# Calculate Weighted Average in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate a weighted average based on the following calculations.

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
item |     Date Sent     |     Date Received
 1   |     2 Feb 10am    |      3 Feb 10am
 1   |     6 Feb 11am    |      6 Feb 12pm
 2   |     2 Feb 10am    |      3 Feb 10am
 2   |     6 Feb 11am    |      6 Feb 12pm
```

I then need to calculate the average based on the time difference rounded down meaning:

```
Time Diff |   Count |
  1       |    2    |
  12      |    2    |
```

So in this case it would be:

```
1 * 2 + 12 * 2 / (12 + 1)
```

I have already written the SQL query to calculate the aggregate table:

```
select 
    floor(datediff(hh, dateSent, dateReceived)) as hrs,
    count(item) as freq 
from 
    table
group by 
    floor(datediff(hh, dateSent, dateReceived))
having 
    floor(datediff(hh, dateSent, dateReceived)) < 100
order by 
    floor(datediff(hh, dateSent, dateReceived)) asc;
```

Should I do a subquery? I am not proficient and I have tried but keep getting syntax errors.

Can somebody help me to get the SQL query to get the weighted average?

Comment: My guess is you actually want to group by the ID in a way like this: `SELECT item, hrs = AVG(DATEDIFF(HOUR, dateSent, dateReceived)), freq = COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY item HAVING AVG(DATEDIFF(HOUR, dateSent, dateReceived)) < 100 ORDER BY 2;` or something like that?

Comment: I actually want to get the weighted average, I thought that this would be a part of the subquery but I haven't managed to get it done. Why do you have the order by 2?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "weighted average". How is it being "weighted"? Also the `order by 2` thing was just lazy short-hand saying "order by the second column".

Comment: The weighted is done by the count in the second table posted in the question. So the weights would be the Time Diff values.

Answer (score 4):

If what you mean by "weighted average" is average of all time differences, then the following may be helpful:

```
select AVG(a.hrs) 
from 
(
    select floor(datediff(hh,dateSent,dateReceived)) as hrs,
    count(item) as freq from table
        group by floor(datediff(hh,dateSent,dateReceived))
            having floor(datediff(hh,dateSent,dateReceived)) <100
--              order by floor(datediff(hh,dateSent,dateReceived)) asc
) a
```

Comment: Yes, this is close enough thanks! I did not know you could do this. My final result is just select sum(a.hrs*a.freq)/sum(a.freq) instead of AVG(a.hrs)